# Set the ForeignKey to value in field of self in Django 2.0 and Python

Tags: python, django

I'm perhaps a little confused as to how ForiegnKey and database relationships work. I have two classes, Coin contains a list of items coin names. CoinData rows of data, containing daily price data for each coin. I want each CoinData to be ForiegnKey tied to their matching item in Coin, and to do this I gave CoinData a 'coin' ForeignKey attribute to my Coin model but all this does is produce a field of 'Coin' options on each CoinData item.

I want to programmatically assign the value in coin_name, to the Coin object it matches with on each row of data. Am I going about this the right way, or am I doing things wrong?

```
class Coin(models.Model):
"""
A class defining all the coins we'll have on the website
"""

# Fields
name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, help_text="Enter coin name")

class CoinData(models.Model):
"""
A class defining the daily coin data
"""

# Fields
coin_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, default='empty')
coin = models.ForeignKey(Coin, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
open_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=10, null=True, help_text="Opening Price")
high_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=10, null=True, help_text="High Price")
low_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=10, null=True, help_text="Low Price")
close_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=10, null=True, help_text="Low Price")
volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=10, null=True, help_text="Volume")
market_cap = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=10, null=True, help_text="Market Cap")
```

Comment: Why save `name` redundantly when you can simply get it from the related object using `coindata_instance.coin.name`?

Comment: You're doing this right. So I wonder what you need really. Do you want your CoinData `coin` field to be automatically set to the corresponding Coin object given the name?

Comment: To add to what Nils Werner said, you don't need a `coin_name` field in `CoinData`. You are linking the objects when you select the appropriate `Coin` object in the dropdown of the `CoinData` form, so you can just access the `name` of the related `Coin`. The exact queries you do to explore the relationship will depend on the data you want to present.

Comment: @pawamoy yes that's exactly what I want to do. I want Coin objects tired to their respective CoinData. At the moment on Django admin, each CoinData has a name, plus the coin field which is a drop down box for everything listed in Coin. I can manually assign (I think) in admin, but i have thousands of records.

Comment: @paulo but how does it know which CoinData matches up to which Coin? I have a list of 900+ coins in Coin and 63,000 CoinData entries. Doing it manually isn't an option. In admin I want users to click on a coin (Coin) then be presented with a number of ways to request the CoinData, along with a default view.

Comment: Are you storing all this for a purpose? Can you not do an api call to coincompaire to avoid making a model?

Comment: @phil0s0pher You can use the ORM programatically in a script, to assign `Coin` objects to `CoinData` objects, as long as you have an appropriate algorithm for the assignment. The relationship between the objects is through the `ForeignKey`, so what I said before about `coin_name` being unnecessary still applies (in fact, it is undesirable, because it denormalizes the database with no gain). Also, for the user to "click on a coin and be presented with a number of ways to request data", you'll probably want to create your own views and not do that in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

So based on your comment, I understand that you have `CoinData` and `Coin` that are related through their `name` field, and you would like to link them with a foreign key instead. Let say you started wrong and want to correct this for future use.

What you already done to fix this:

1. You added the foreign key field named `coin` in `CoinData` model to reference a `Coin` model instance.

What I would suggest to finish fixing this is:

1. Write a script (or run a few commands in a Python shell) to automatically update all `CoinData` instances to reference their related `Coin` instances, given their respective `name` field:

   ```
   for coin_data in CoinData.objects.all():
       try:
           related_coin = Coin.objects.get(name=coin_data.name)
           coin_data.coin = related_coin
           coin_data.save()
       except Coin.DoesNotExist:
           print('no related Coin instance for %s' % coin_data)
   ```
2. Add instructions for when a `CoinData` instance is created to reference it's related `Coin` instance (so you don't have to do it later, and you can make sure every `CoinData` is linked to a `Coin`): `coin_data = CoinData.objects.create(coin=related_coin, ...)`
3. Remove the `name` field from `CoinData` as it is redundant with the name in `Coin` model.

Answer (score -2):

If you simply want to say "this specific Coin Data refers to this specific Coin", you would reference the Coin data to the Coin using a foreign key. If you want to get, for example, the associated Coin Name for a Coin Data, you could use

`coin_data = CoinData.objects.get(pk=1) #example
coin_name = coin_data.coin.name`

You would need a `name` field on your `CoinData` model if a `CoinData` instance must have a specific name.